# Problemas al agregar un método a una clase

Tags: javascript, poo

estoy creando la clase 'Persona' y requiero agregarle el método datos() al prototype de la clase por medio de la función agregarMetodo(), pero las variables this.nombre y this.edad en el metodo datos() no están accediendo a los atributos de la clase, al momento de retornar me regresa 'undefined, undefined años'

```
class Persona {
      constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, domicilio) {
          // Crea el constructor:
          this.nombre = nombre;
          this.apellido = apellido;
          this.edad = edad;
          this.domicilio = domicilio;
      }

    detalle = () =>{
       return {
          Nombre : this.nombre,
          Apellido : this.apellido,
          Edad : this.edad,
          Domicilio : this.domicilio
       }
    }
}

function crearInstanciaPersona(nombre, apellido, edad, dir) {
  //Con esta función vamos a crear una nueva persona a partir de nuestro constructor de 
  //persona (creado en el ejercicio anterior)
  //Recibirá los valores "Juan", "Perez", 22, "Saavedra 123" para sus respectivas 
  //propiedades
  //Devolver la nueva persona creada
  let person = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, dir);
  return person
}

function agregarMetodo() {
   //La función agrega un método "datos" a la clase Persona que toma el nombre y la edad 
   //de la persona y devuelve: 
   //Ej: "Juan, 22 años"
   Persona.prototype.datos = () =>{
       return `${this.nombre}, ${this.edad} años`
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas usando [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`arrow functions`). Esto provoca que `this` sea el contexto donde la función fue definida y no el de la clase.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente tenes que usar funciones normales.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre, apellido, edad, domicilio) {
    // Crea el constructor:
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.domicilio = domicilio;
  }

  detalle = () => {
    return {
      Nombre: this.nombre,
      Apellido: this.apellido,
      Edad: this.edad,
      Domicilio: this.domicilio
    }
  }
}

function crearInstanciaPersona(nombre, apellido, edad, dir) {
  let person = new Persona(nombre, apellido, edad, dir);
  return person
}

function agregarMetodo() {
  // ACA - Usamos funcion normal (no flecha)
  Persona.prototype.datos = function() {
    return `${this.nombre}, ${this.edad} años`
  }
}

// Test
let p = crearInstanciaPersona('Jhon', 'Doe', 1000, 'N/D');
agregarMetodo();
console.log('detalle:', p.detalle());
console.log('datos:', p.datos());
```